# How to run the Microsoft Windows XP VHD, for testing with IE 6.0, with a valid/un-expired date?

Tags: internet-explorer, virtual, vhd, vpc

I just downloaded the VHD for windows xp:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575

But when I start the virtual pc it says that "the evaluation period for this copy of windows has ended..."

I read that for the Windows XP image:

"Expires: This image will shutdown and become completely unusable on August 09, 2011."

Why is it expired? where could I download a working version?

Thanks

Comment: It works when you boot into safe mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: http://www.nirsoft.net/blog/2008/12/running-operating-system-inside-virtual.html

Ran it with 01/07/2011 date.

Comment: This is insufficient without also setting `preferences/hardware/bios/time_sync_at_boot` to `false` as detailed here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprovirt/thread/aca326fd-8e37-49f3-8b90-4eda93a11cd6

Answer (score 13):

**Note 1**: I'm running the [XP IE6 VHD which expires today, 4/4/12](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575) (this VHD can also be upgraded to IE7 and IE8 - I use all three in three separate VMs) under the Windows 7 version of Virtual PC - your mileage may vary.

**Note 2**: As of today (the expiration date of the VHD), this VHD tells me it's expired upon login, and won't even get me to the desktop.  If I simply reset the date and disable time syncing as follows, there is still an "expired" flag set somewhere in the VHD's Windows install and it's still unusable.  You **must** either:

- discard your undo disk to a point prior to the expiration (if you already had Undo Disks enabled, which I always recommend when creating a VM for testing to "lock down" your setup once you have it the way you like),

  **or**
- reinstall a fresh VHD dated prior to the expiration date, then make the following changes to the .VMC file **before** booting the VHD for the first time.

### **How I got my working XP IE VHD back**:

1. You need to change the date in the .VMC file per [step 1B in the link @William mentioned](http://www.nirsoft.net/blog/2008/12/running-operating-system-inside-virtual.html).  This value may not exist in a new, unbooted .VMC file - it should go under `preferences/hardware/bios` like this example for Dec 31, 2011 @ 12:00am:

   ```
   <preferences>
     <hardware>
       <bios>
         <time_bytes type="bytes">00000000000000311211</time_bytes>
   ```

   If you **do not** set this to some valid date before booting the VHD for the first time (in which case this value won't exist yet), it will force a time sync (even if you disable time syncing as in step 2 below), which may completely foil your efforts.
2. But you **also** need to disable time syncing in the .VMC file per the information in [this TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprovirt/thread/aca326fd-8e37-49f3-8b90-4eda93a11cd6) (scroll down to karonwu's 2nd post, 7/16/09 7:41am).

   Disable time syncing at boot (this value didn't exist by default in my .VMC file):

   ```
   <preferences>
     <hardware>
       <bios>
         <time_sync_at_boot type="boolean">false</time_sync_at_boot>
   ```

   Disable repeated time syncing while VHD is running (this value was already present and set to "true"):

   ```
   <preferences>
     <integration>
       <microsoft>
         <host_time_sync>
           <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
   ```

You **may** want to go into `Control Panel` -> `Date and Time` -> `Internet Time`, and uncheck "Automatically synchronize".  Although this didn't seem necessary in my case - I forgot on one of my VMs and it said it synchronized successfully, yet the date and time remained as I had set them in the .VMC file.

As recommended by @Leonid below, you should also disable Automatic Updates to prevent an older version of Internet Explorer (such as 6 or 7) from upgrading itself (note that IE8 is the last version supported by XP).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm... couldnt care less about my data on the VM but it would be nice if MS made it easier to use their IE tester! Quite typical :)

Comment: thanks! I'd also recommend to disable automatic updates. Otherwise one morning your browser will gladly report that it's just successfully upgraded to IE8...

Comment: @Leonid: good point, I learned that lesson the hard way once already ;)

Comment: Great info, but not getting any joy here... when you say "discard your undo disk" how do you do this if you can't log in? Settings GUI option is greyed out.

Comment: @MemeDeveloper: In the virtual machine's settings, under Undo Disks, if there is no check mark next to "Enable Undo Disks", then you don't have any undo disk to discard, and no way to roll back to a point prior to the "expired" flag being set - you'll have to install a fresh VHD and make the above changes to the VMC file *before* booting the VHD for the first time.  If you *do* have Undo Disks enabled, but the "Discard  Changes" button is grayed out, make sure your VM is hibernated or shut down first.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://www.modern.ie Downloaded XP WITH IE 8 works for me.

Upd 2018: now Microsoft close this website and make redirect to download Edge.

Comment: This works seamlessly with virtualbox for Windows. XP IE8 download is 1.02GB. The OVA image imports into VB easily and it's ready to go.

Comment: Looks like they have removed xp. win7 is available there

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft usually posts new ones when the old ones expire. I sent an e-mail.

The response I got was:

> It's being worked on and first batch *should* be ready today.
>   Apologies to anyone for the inconvenience.

So... try again later today.

Answer (score 0):

The guy who kindly dealt with it [last time](http://twitter.com/#!/petele/status/26266676384) has [moved on](http://twitter.com/#!/petele/status/80311231415713793). From his suggestion, it might be worth pinging @ie just before expiration next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just went to the website again and now it says :
"Expires: This image will shutdown and become completely unusable on November 17, 2011."

File is now 366Mb down from 500Mb and it works, but now you have to enter a password which you get from clicking the "hint" button...

Answer (score 0):

The site has been updated with new images which expire on 4 April 2012.

Haven't tested them, but looks good.

Everyone put this in your diary for the first week of March and remind MS to put up new ones.

I saw a couple of people complaining on Twitter about this, maybe that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the advice from @acatalept unfortunately to no avail. So ended up downloading again, newer version.... from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575 working fine now... except for the fact it's whole purpose is running IE6 - which is obviously far from "fine" ;)

Answer (score 0):

This answer by  in this thread is working as of today: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprovirt/thread/aca326fd-8e37-49f3-8b90-4eda93a11cd6

Quoting the answer that matters:

1)  I found out that .vmc and .vmcx files are NOT the same.  If you found your .vmcx files, don't bother opening them up in a text editor for this issue.  Instead, find the .vmc files (in Windows 7, they are found under C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines).

2)  Shut down your virtual PC environment (I was using XP Mode).  This was the step that I thought I could get around.  I kept hibernating and making changes to the vmc file, but the changes did not work until after I completely shut down, made the changes to the .vmc file and booted back up.

3) As for what changes are necessary:  If you are able to run the VBS script provided by SANDY.WADHWA [MSFT], good for you.  If not, you can make the changes manually.

In the .vmc file, find the section:

```xml
 <integration>
  <microsoft>
   <mouse>
    <allow type="boolean">true</allow>
   </mouse>
```

I made the changes manually by first adding the section:

```xml
<components>
  <host_time_sync>
    <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
  </host_time_sync>
</components>
```

This was wrong for my XP Mode (it may work on a VPC 2007 environment, though, so give it a try).
Then, I removed the  tags **(NOTE: I did this as well, and this worked - you probably want to do this option)**:

```xml
<host_time_sync>
  <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
</host_time_sync>
```

That allowed me to make a change to the time and date without it automatically reverting back every 5-10 seconds.

4) If you would like to prevent the VPC environment from synchronizing upon bootup, do put the following inside the  tag:

```xml
<time_sync_at_boot type="boolean">false</time_sync_at_boot>
```

Again, keep in mind that you must SHUT DOWN the VPC in order for the changes in the .vmc file to take effect.

5) One last thing, if you go into the Date and Time Properties and click the Internet Time tab, uncheck the "Automatically synchronize with an Internet time server" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for running Internet Explorer 6 on Windows 10 in a Windows XP VM using Hyper-V:

1. Install Hyper-V
2. Install 7-Zip
3. Download [XP Mode](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002)
4. Right-click `WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe` > 7-Zip > Open Archive
5. `Sources` > `xpm` > Extract
6. Right-click `xpm` > 7-Zip > Open Archive
7. `VirtualXPVHD` > Extract
8. Append `.vhd` to the filename
9. Create the VM in Hyper-V with an existing VHD
10. Remove the default Network Adapter in the VM's settings and add a Legacy Network Adapter connected to the Default Switch
11. Start the VM and install Windows XP